# Pop up blocker problem

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="post" name="first" target="_blank" id="first">
    <img src="loader.gif"  id="icon"/>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#icon").click(function(){
document.first.submit();
})
//setTimeout("document.first.submit()", 1 * 500);
```

In this, while clicking the image, it will submit the form and new tab will open with 'http://www.google.com'

When i do the same functionality, on setTimeout  or in page load, it will produce popup bloker, how can we avoid the pop up blocker

Comment: Most browsers have a built-in check: if a user clicks, popups are allowed; if it's programmatic, popups are blocked. Why are you trying to bypass the mechanism that prevents popups from appearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Popup blockers work by blocking popups that haven't been triggered by a users action. That is why it is working on click.

Unfortunately, you won't be able to get it to work without user interaction unless you get the users to explicitly allow popups from your site which I imagine would be quite difficult to convince them.

Comment: Hi
i have tried to submit the form ,using  the javascript  events like mouseenter,mousemove....But they also have pop up blocker problem.But these events are triggered by user.So let me know any other solutions.
Its working in a reference site(http://www.dealbase.com/flight-deals),
 after submitting the 'check rates' button

Comment: It must be a *click* event. Not mousemove, mouseenter, mouseleave, etc. You can understand why popups triggered by these events would be blocked because it's not a direct action performed by a user.